# how to take out the second and third elements(like c(3,5),c(5,7)) in every 1500 cols at one time and inform one matrix

Tags: r

```
a <- list(c(1,3,5), c(22,5,7),c(7,9,10))
```

there are 1500 cols (like c(1,3,5),c(22,5,7) in one list. i would like to take out the second and third elements(like c(3,5),c(5,7)) in every 1500 cols at one time and inform one matrix. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you need :

```
sapply(a, `[`, 2:3)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    5    9
#[2,]    5    7   10
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tail`

```
sapply(a, tail, 2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    5    9
#[2,]    5    7   10
```